# How to show output on screen?

Tags: c++, arrays

I am practicing arrays and pointers from Alex Allain book.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int *growArray (int* p_values, int cur_size);

int main ()
{
  int next_element = 0;
  int size = 10;
  int *p_values = new int[ size ];
  int val;
  cout << "Please enter a number: ";
  cin >> val;
  while ( val > 0 )
  {
    if ( size == next_element + 1 )
    {
      // now all we need to do is implement growArray
      p_values = growArray( p_values, size );
    }
    p_values[ next_element ] = val;
    cout << "Please enter a number (or 0 to exit): ";
    cin >> val;
  }
}

int *growArray (int* p_values, int cur_size)
{
  int *p_new_values = new int[ cur_size * 2 ];
  for ( int i = 0; i < cur_size; ++i )
  {
    p_new_values[ i ] = p_values[ i ];
    cout << p_new_values[ i ] << endl;
  }
  delete p_values;
  return p_new_values;
}
```

But when I execute code

```
Please enter a number: 6
Please enter a number (or 0 to exit): 0
```

Why am I missing screen output for `p_new_values` array? Is it allowed to put `cout` in function definition or not?

Comment: Are you sure, there isn't a `next_element++` missing somewhere?

Comment: If you read the book more carefully you'll see that, in your code, the line `p_values = growArray( p_values, size );` is missing an ampersand ("&") and that the  `growArray` function you wrote is very different from the one in the book.

Comment: even with `next_element++`, i'm still not sure what this example is about

Comment: maybe `growArray` should update `size` as well?

Comment: And the book code's comment immediately preceding the call to `growArray` is significant. For whatever reason, you didn't copy the important part of it in your code.

Comment: @molbdnilo Which part?

Comment: @KizaRajak Everything that you didn't copy is the important part. That is, "Notice that we need to pass in size as a pointer since we need to keep track of the size of the array as it grows!" is important.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if ( size == next_element + 1 )
{
    // now all we need to do is implement growArray
    p_values = growArray( p_values, size );
}
```

`size` will never be `next_element + 1`, so your `growArray` function will never be called. I'm not sure what you mean to express with that check, but you should re-think your program's logic.

Comment: I understand,but example is really from the book.

Comment: In that case, I suggest burning said book.

Comment: The code in the book is OK. The problem is caused by careless copying and not reading the comments in the book's code.

Answer (score 2):

Please note that your `size` will be equal to the `next_element + 1` when `next_element` is just 1 more than the current array and hence the function `growArray()` will called at specific points of program when the `next_element` is `size-1` and so on.

```
if ( size == next_element + 1 )
{
    // now all we need to do is implement growArray
    p_values = growArray( p_values, size );
}
```

Also, nowhere the variable `next_element` is getting **updated** to make the condition a valid logic.

You can replace the following line:

```
p_values[ next_element ] = val;
```

with

```
p_values[ next_element++ ] = val;
```

**Final Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int *growArray (int* p_values, int *cur_size);   //Changed

int main ()
{
  int next_element = 0;
  int size = 10;
  int *p_values = new int[ size ];
  int val;
  cout << "Please enter a number: ";
  cin >> val;
  while ( val > 0 )
  {
    if ( size == next_element + 1 )
    {
      // now all we need to do is implement growArray
      p_values = growArray( p_values, &size );    //Changed
    }
    p_values[ next_element++ ] = val;    //Changed
    cout << "Please enter a number (or 0 to exit): ";
    cin >> val;
  }
}

int *growArray (int* p_values, int *cur_size)    //Changed
{
  *cur_size = *cur_size * 2;                     //Changed
  int *p_new_values = new int[ *cur_size];       //Changed
  for ( int i = 0; i < *cur_size; ++i )          //Changed
  {
    p_new_values[ i ] = p_values[ i ];
    cout << p_new_values[ i ] << endl;
  }
  delete p_values;
  return p_new_values;
}
```

Comment: this one's a better answer

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to print the values only if the case of using `*growArray()` function arises, because the printing statements are inside the `*growArray()` function.

And it is perfectly fine to use `cout` inside function definitions.

[edit] and yes as pointed above, you are not changinf the parameter `next_element`, so should recheck your logic maybe.